# Ratio of numbers to string length in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I've been reading about Java 8 in the past, and I know it supports streams, but I have not yet looked into it that much.

I am wondering how much cleaner my code could be with Java 8.

I have the following:

```
public static float ratioNumbers(final String input) {
    int countNumbers = 0;
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        countNumbers += (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return countNumbers * 1.0f / input.length();
}
```

What would be the most concise way to write this? With still retaining proper intendation.

Comment: The streams API will just slow down the code and the way you have it is very explanatory by looking at it. I suggest you leave it the way it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
long numberOfDigits = input.codePoints().filter(Character::isDigit).count();
return 1f * numberOfDigits / input.length();
```

Answer (score 5):

I would do like this :

```
 public static float ratioNumbers(final String input) {
    return input.chars().filter(c -> Character.isDigit(c)).count()/(float)input.length();
 }
```

Instead of using streams, you can also use a regex to remove all-non digits characters :

```
public static float ratioNumbers(final String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "").length()* 1.0f/input.length();
}
```